# What should we do when we get to know that our mother is doing something wrong? Should we talk to her or stay silent?

Tags: islamic-scholar

What should I do with regards to **Islamic Point** of view when my mother is doing something wrong. Please answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

You should talk to her politely and try to help her realize.
Ignoring is considered bad in such a situation, as Allah tells us. Enjoining to Good [Ma’ruf] and Forbidding from Evil [Munkar]

Comment: Thank you for helping. JazakAllah

Comment: You are welcome. It would good if you considered accepting the answer.